# Set the keyboard modifier for process exec

Tags: c#, windows

I have a windows application I would like to start with the shift key depressed. However it is being started over citrix which means that we can't hold the shift key as that doesn't translate in a sensible fashion. I was thinking that perhaps I could write a holster application which would fork and exec while simulating the shift key. I have, however, been unable to find a way to set the modifiers during launch. Any ideas?

Comment: could you explain "we can't hold the shift key as that doesn't translate in a sensible fashion" ?

Comment: might help if you can give some more context - why the shift key?  is this to get a new instance instead of an existing on out of the Win7 taskbar?  What is having the shift key pressed going to change?

Comment: The shift key is used by the application, in this case access, to bypass the startup macros. However in citrix you launch the application by clicking on a link on a website which executes the process on a remote server. Holding shift in the browser doesn't translate to holding shift on the server.

Comment: ah, ok.  I've not used it before, but with a quick search, one workaround might be to start the app (Access) by itself and then hold Shift while opening the database (instead of starting Access by opening a database file).  You might also use one of the command-line switches or try to use some of the keyboard code in this post: http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0068.htm